# Scala: Implementing Java Interface results in incompatible Type

Tags: java, scala, types, interface

i have a Java-Interface that i want to implement in Scala. The Interface contains the following method-declaration:

```
  public Boolean existsTable(String tableId);
```

My Scala-Implementation is:

```
  override def existsTable(tableId: String): Boolean = {
    val dbmeta = connection.getMetaData()
    val dbtables = dbmeta.getTables(null, null, channelId, null)
    if (dbtables.next())
      // table exists
      return true
    else
      return false
  }
```

For some reason i get the error
"overriding method existsTable in trait xyz
 of type (tableId: String)Boolean; method existsTable has incompatible type"

But i dont really know where there could be an incompatible type since its just a Boolean that is the return-type?

Greetings.

PS: I had this method working once before in the exact way, when i wasnt implementing an interface, so there should be no error in the method itself. It's just the Implementation of the Java-Interface in Scala that's giving me a hard time.

Comment: note: `public` modifier on interface method declarations is redundant; also, why not just `return dbtables.next()`? (and why `Boolean` and not `boolean` while we're at it?)

Comment: Hello, well if i write "boolean" then scala doesn't recognize that type. :)  But i changed it to just return dbtablex.next(), so thx for that. Unfortunately it's still complaining about the incompatible type...

Comment: you need java's Boolean: `override def existsTable(tableId: String): java.lang.Boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is not working, as indicated in the comments is that Scala's Boolean is not the same as Java's Boolean.  A quick way to fix this is:

```
import java.lang.{Boolean => JBoolean}

override def existsTable(tableId: String): JBoolean
```

By aliasing the type, it's a little more clear what you meant to return.  You could of course just define it as:

```
override def existsTable(tableId: String): java.lang.Boolean
```

Comment: Both this and the answer suggested in the comments force the use of the Java `Boolean` type, which is less interoperable with Scala, and forces boxing all the time (which looks unnecessary in this situation). Changing the Java interface to use `boolean` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Scala's `Boolean` corresponds to Java's `boolean`, not Java's `Boolean`. If you change the Java return type to `boolean` but leave the Scala one as `Boolean` it should work.

Scala raises all primitive types to the level of real objects, letting the compiler decide to box/unbox them as necessary depending on how they're used. Java, on the other hand, maintains two representations of primitive types: the primitive type itself (small letter) and a boxed representation (capital letter).